# Getting TransactionInDoubtException when used single Transaction scope

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, transactionscope

I am using Transaction Scope in below manner,

```
var option1 = new TransactionOptions();
        option1.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        option1.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tide:TransactionTimeout"]))
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, option1))
                {
                        //delete data from database
                        //multiple BulkInsertData in different tables of database
                        //update data
                        transactionScope.Complete();
                }
```

There is no inner transaction started. I got TransactionInDoubtException, I can't understand why it has occurred. Previously code run smoothly, but suddenly from yesterday, this exception throws

> System.Transactions.TransactionInDoubtException: The transaction is in doubt. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment enlistment)     --- End of inner exception stack trace

Comment: Although it's probably not the cause of your problem (at least I don't think so), your `try .. catch` block is wrong. The scope will already be disposed by the `using`, there is no need to do it again in the `catch`. The entire block is superfluous if you're not doing anything with `exception`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will make changes in my code

Comment: After making changes, same error is regenerate

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with your transaction handling code. Can you post some more of your database call please? Do you get the error if you simply send a command like "select * from sys.objects" ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated the database call in question. In transaction scope, we do not execute any select statements, I hope you will get what you want

Comment: Is there an inner exception? What is the full exception being thrown? Often the underlying cause can be a timeout...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have updated exception in Question

Comment: Looks like the error stems from the SQL. Are there BEGIN TRAN...COMMIT TRAN statements in SQL stored procedures you are running? If so are the transactions being rolled back in the event of an error? If not then the COMMIT TRAN will be executed after the transaction has failed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, there are no begin and commit transactions in SQL procedure, and we are using transaction scope, so we only use the above code block. if the transaction is failed then code must be out of using block, I think there is no chance of calling COMMIT TRANSACTION

Comment: Have you run SQL Profiler against the database? If you do this at the statement level you should be able to see what is calling the COMMIT TRANSATION immediately prior to the error.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, We are using Azure SQL database, so not able to connect it to SQL Profiler

Comment: Can you not use [the SQL Profiler extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=azuresqldb-current)?

Answer (score 4):

From the exception message

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

it seems likely that you are running some SQL that is not handling errors correctly. Do you have anything like this in the SQL that is run?

```
BEGIN TRAN

-- Some SQL here that generates an error

COMMIT TRAN
```

In this case any error within the `BEGIN TRAN...` clause will cause the transaction to fail. When `COMMIT TRAN` is then called the transaction state cannot be determined, hence the `TransactionInDoubt` exception. You need to make sure you call `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning of your procedures and handle errors correctly:

```
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
   -- Some SQL here that generates an error
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message()
   RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
   RETURN 55555
END CATCH
```

See [this article on error handling in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern)